# IPhone tabbar application error

Tags: iphone

I have created Xcode iPhone project using TabBarController template.

[image]

I hope FirstViewController links to an UIView(View1).
**So I add an UIView name View1.Xib and set it as the outlet view of FirstViewController.
Then I removed original view under 'Selected First View Controller (First)** shown as picture below

[image]

Then I set as ad hoc version and build&Run

It installed on my ipod, but it reported

```
Thu Nov 25 19:25:59 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[2591] <Warning>: debugserver-43 for armv6 Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Apple, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Thu Nov 25 19:25:59 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[2591] <Warning>: Connecting to com.apple.debugserver service...
Thu Nov 25 19:26:03 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[2591] <Warning>: 1 [0a1f/0903]: error: ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0103, pid = 2585, task => 0x0000 ) 0x000001f5/0x000001f5 0x000001f5/0x000001f5 err = (os/kern) failure (0x00000005)
Thu Nov 25 19:26:03 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[2591] <Error>: error: MachTask::StartExceptionThread (): task invalid, exception thread start failed.
Thu Nov 25 19:26:09 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[2591] <Warning>: 2 [0a1f/0903]: error: ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0103, pid = 2585, task => 0x0000 ) 0x000001f5/0x000001f5 0x000001f5/0x000001f5 err = (os/kern) failure (0x00000005)
Thu Nov 25 19:26:09 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[2591] <Warning>: 3 [0a1f/0903]: RNBRunLoopLaunchInferior DNBProcessLaunch() returned error: ''
Thu Nov 25 19:26:09 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[2591] <Warning>: error: failed to launch process (null): failed to get the task for process 2585
Thu Nov 25 19:26:09 unknown com.apple.debugserver-43[2591] <Warning>: 4 [0a1f/1603]: error: ::read ( 7, 0x28091c, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Thu Nov 25 19:26:09 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.product[0x64d5]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:2649 (23909):10
Thu Nov 25 19:26:09 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.product[0x64d5]) Working around 5020256. Assuming the job crashed.
Thu Nov 25 19:26:09 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.company.product[0x64d5]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault
Thu Nov 25 19:26:09 unknown SpringBoard[24] <Warning>: Application 'tabbar' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault
```

What's wrong with my change?
I am not familiar with UITabBarController, it really make me headache for a week

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing like this do as follows,
In mainwindow.xib,
Select the tab bar item
[image]

Then set the xib value in inspector,

[image]

Then set the class,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i Think u not set the Class of you ViewController in identity inspector Than after add view nib files on tab view...